# Beginner: How do I say "any superclass of generic A"

Tags: generics, scala

I'm playing with the QuickSort example at the start of [Scala By Example](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf) and trying to adapt it for a generic type `A`, rather than just `Int`s.

What I've got working so far is

```
def sort[A <: Ordered[A]](xs: Array[A])
```

Which allows `sort` to run on all types that are reflexively ordered, <s>like [`RichBoolean`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.3/scala/runtime/RichBoolean.html)</s>.

But what I'd also like to allow types `A` where they extend `Ordered[B]` where B is a superclass of A (so, for instance, anything that extends `Ordered[Any]`).

How can I say this?

---

What I actually got to work, thanks to [agilesteel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8946052/9859):

```
case class X( i : Int ) extends Ordered[X] {
  def compare( x : X ) = x.i - i
}

class Y( i : Int, j : Int ) extends X(i)

case class Z( i : Int ) extends Ordered[Any] {
  def compare( a : Any ) : Int = {
    if (! a.isInstanceOf[Z] ) 
      sys.error("whoops") 

    val z = a.asInstanceOf[Z]
    z.i - i
  }
}

object QuickSort {
  def main( args : Array[String] ) {
    val xs = Array( 3, 1, 2, 4 ) map X
    sort( xs );
    val ys = Array( 3, 1, 2, 4 ) map { i => new Y(i, -i) }
    sort[X,Y]( ys );
    val zs = Array( 3, 1, 2, 4 ) map Z
    sort[Any,Z]( zs );
  }
  def sort[B >: A, A <: Ordered[B]](xs: Array[A]) {
    def swap(i: Int, j: Int) {
      val t = xs(i); xs(i) = xs(j); xs(j) = t;
    }
    def sort1(l: Int, r: Int) {
      val pivot = xs((l + r) / 2)
        var i = 1; var j = r
      while (i <= j) {
        while (xs(i) < pivot) i += 1
        while (xs(j) > pivot) j -= 1
        if (i <= j) {
          swap(i, j)
          i += 1
          j += 1
        }
      }
      if (l < j) sort1(l, j)
      if (j < r) sort1(i, r)
    }
    sort1(0, xs.length - 1)
  }
}
```

I was misled by trying to use `RichLong` and `RichBoolean` as test types, since they aren't actuallly reflexively `Ordered` (they extend `Ordered[Long]` and `Ordered[Boolean]` instead).

Comment: Maybe you're referring to "any subclass" instead of "any superclass"? As far as the rest of the answer is concerned, please have a look below.

Comment: @fotNelton: No, what I want is forall a : A, a < b is defined for b : B, where B is a (not necessarily proper) superset of A.  Given that I'm actually operating on an `Array[A]`, I won't actually be comparing a < c for any c in B \ A, but I don't want to rule out types A where they implement `Ordered[Any]` rather than `Ordered[A]`.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. Have to think about it though. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def sort[B >: A, A <: Ordered[B]](xs: Array[B])
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is something that either derives from the `Ordered` trait or can be viewed as such. There's a whole lot of implicit conversion (called views) from many classes to `Ordered`, and you can have your own as well. However, you end up with:

`def sort[A <% Ordered[A]](xs: Array[A]) = ...`

The `<%` is nothing but syntactic sugar for `def sort(xs: Array[A])(implicit cv: A => Ordered[A]) = ...`. You might want to have a look at this nice [compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info) of questions and answers if you're interesting in what's going on behind the scenes of implicits.

Comment: This works for class `X`, but not for class `Y` or `Z`, above:  `error: diverging implicit expansion for type Y => Ordered[Y]`

Comment: Yeah, well, I read your question once again and realised I overlooked the actual question at the end (before the final edit). My fault.